# Suspendable subscription in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, subscription, observable

I need to suspend a subscription in knockout.
The reason is, after an observable is changed, it is necessary sometimes to change its value, and with subscription it ends up in recursion.

I found the following 
[SuspendableSubscription](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/270)

but I don't really know how to use it.

My code is

```
this.SearchParam.ProjectTypes.suspendableSubscribe(changeProjectType);
//....
function changeProjectType() {
    // my changes on this.SearchParam.ProjectTypes observable
}
```

But how do I suspend the subscription to prevent *changeProjectType* to be called recursively?

Or maybe I'm using the wrong tool for the job, and there are better options?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to include logic that changes an observable as it's being updated, perhaps you should instead use a [writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)

Comment: May be Rate-limiting observable notifications (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) help you? In earlier it was "throttle" extender.

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal repro of a scenario where you want to use this. Without it we're in the dark trying to help you with your *actual* problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursion problem like this I would normally treat as a "code smell". It would strongly suggest that the way you're doing it is possibly the wrong approach.

Leaving that aside and assuming the approach is right, a simple way to avoid recursive calls would be to add a flag that stops it happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/ea6cqq5n/

This is a simple form and viewModel that trim an input and convert to upper case. It has a `nameEditing` flag: when set to true we are in the subscribe event, so we ignore any recursive subscription events.

```
   // flag to prevent recursion
    self.nameEditing = false;
```

In the subscription we first check this flag, and if not set, we set before making changes, and unset when those are complete.

```
 self.Name.subscribe(function (newName) {
        if (!self.nameEditing) {
            // prevent recursion
            self.nameEditing = true;
            // change the observable
            if (newName) {
                // clean up value
                self.Name(newName.trim().toUpperCase());
            }
            self.nameEditing = false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. The code cannot be designed differently. The observable is an array, and among possible selections there is a value - All. When that is selected, all other values must be removed. And if a "regular" value is selected, the code should check and remove the All value. And this cause the recursion

Comment: Code can _always_ be designed differently! Tricky to advise without more context, but you might want to consider a .computed value that determines the result, based on the observableArray values.